# Interrogation about Spring MVC test API's model().attribute() method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito, hamcrest, spring-mvc-test

I am trying to test the following controller method using the **Spring MVC test API**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/preference/email", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
public String emailForm(@ModelAttribute EmailInfo emailInfo, Model model, @CurrentMember Member member) {
    emailInfo.setEmail(member.getEmail());
    emailInfo.setActivated(member.isActivated());
    emailInfo.setToken(member.getToken());
    model.addAttribute("emailInfo", emailInfo);
    return "preference";
}
```

When I **debug** the following test method...

```
@Test
    public void shouldPopulateEmailInfo() throws Exception {
        when(currentMemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.supportsParameter(any(MethodParameter.class))).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        when(currentMemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(any(MethodParameter.class), any(ModelAndViewContainer.class), any(NativeWebRequest.class), any(WebDataBinderFactory.class))).thenReturn(currentMember);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/preference/email"))//
                .andDo(print())//
                .andExpect(model().attribute("emailInfo.email", "currentMember@example.com"));//
    }
```

... I do see that "**currentMember@example.com**" is set on the **email field of emailInfo**.

However, I systematically get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'emailInfo.email' expected:<currentMember@example.com> but was:<null>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ModelResultMatchers$2.match(ModelResultMatchers.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
    at com.bignibou.tests.controller.preference.PreferenceControllerEmailManagementTest.shouldPopulateEmailInfo(PreferenceControllerEmailManagementTest.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

There is something I don't get with the Spring Mvc Test API.... Can anyone please help?

**edit**: Here is what I have come up with after taking into account the provided answer:

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("emailInfo", Matchers.hasProperty("email", Matchers.equalTo("currentMember@example.com"))));//
```

It works fine now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Sotirios pointed out, `model().attribute("attributeName")` wont allow you to navigate and it will use the whole thing as a name.

However you can use this method instead:

```
public <T> ResultMatcher attribute(final String name, final Matcher<T> matcher)
```

This will allow you to specify a Hamcrest matcher to match agains your attributes like:

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("emailInfo", hasProperty("email", is("currentMember@example.com"))))
```

Just make sure you have the Hamcrest library in your classpath and import it like:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*
```

Note: To import is specially important if you are using Groovy for your tests (Spock) as the method names in Hamcrest conflict with the Groovy standard library

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Additionally, you can use this recursively: `andExpect(model().attribute("person", hadProperty("emailInfo", hasProperty("email", is("currentMember@example.com"))));`

Answer (score 8):

`Model` attributes are String-key Object-value pairs. There is no expression resolving going on. When you do

```
model().attribute("emailInfo.email", "currentMember@example.com"));//
```

You are asking if there is a `Model` attribute with key `emailInfo.email` that has the specified value. The answer is obviously no since you don't have a `Model` attribute with such a key.

What you have is

```
model.addAttribute("emailInfo", emailInfo);
```

which is a `Model` attribute with key `emailInfo` that holds an object of type `EmailInfo`. You'll need to compare the `email` field of the `EmailInfo` object yourself.

Comment: How can I resolve "The method model() is undefined for the type "

Comment: @Jesse That's a `static` method of `MockMvcResultMatchers`. Import it appropriately.